# Querying A Datable Using Linq Returning Distinct Values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am attempting to get distinct values from a datatable column. here is my code..

```
var sourceItems = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                              .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Source").ToString())
                              .Select(x => x.First());
ddlSource.DataSource = sourceItems;
ddlSource.DataBind();
```

This code is returning 4 rows of `System.Data.DataRow` as the values. I need the actual values stored in the rows not the row type. Also is this code a proper way to grab only distinct values in the column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var sourceItems = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(x => x.Field<string>("Source"))
                              .Distinct()
                              .ToList();
```

Note that `.ToList()` can be skipped, but of course it depends on what the `DataSource` property of the `ddlSource` object is able to accept. If It's a winforms control I suspect `ToList` is necessary.

Your code does basically the same as this one, but you must change the last `Select` into `Select(x => x.Key)` to select the values that are used to group the rows, and not the first row.
Also your code has more overhead than using `Distinct`, since `GroupBy` creates subgroups of the original collection.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `.Distinct` extension method?

```
ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => x.Field<string>("Source").ToString())
  .Distinct()
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var sourceItems = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
                         .Select(x => x.Field<string>("Source")) 
                         .Distinct()
                         .ToList();
     ddlSource.DataSource = sourceItems; 
     ddlSource.DataBind();
```

(You don't need to call `.ToString()` on a string, so I've removed that.)

Comment: This works fine but when I display it back in the dropdown its diplaying 1 character for each line for some reason. Do I have to convert sourceItems to a List or datable or something before I set it to the datasource?

Comment: @NickLaMarca there are a couple of possibilities.  Probably calling .ToList() will solve the problem.  I've edited the code accordingly.